# SSRS change default DataSet

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report with a dataset from a certain database. I've gone to the trouble of creating a query that (hopefully) imports the data from a more accurate source. What I want to do is potentially delete the first source, and then use the second source. However the only thing I've found online tells me I must:

`=First(Field!MyField.Value,"Better Source")`

I really just want to try to switch everything out.

Comment: Why don't you just change your Dataset? Make sure everything is named identical as it is Case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you added a new/replaced the current DataSet with the new query, you can change the column names to match the ones in the current Tablix/Matrix (the same Aliases/names within the Query Designer).

That way, your fields will be within the DataSet and you will see Fields!Myfield.Value instead of First(Fields!Myfield.Value)

Let me know if that helps